# Is it possible to get around the Cross-Origin limitation when calling the Google Places API Web service?

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible enable the [Google Placess API WebService](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#api_key/) to allow cross-origin requests from my domain so that I can access the service directly from the browser? I'v been experimenting with the API-keys by creating a Browser API key and then adding my domain to the referers list, but to no avail. Not sure if that is what the refeferer property is for anyway.

Is this limitation by design, or am I missing something here?

Google Places API WebService is the service that I want to use. Neither the Places Autocomplete or Places Search in the [Places Library](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html) are suitable for my particular requirement.

Cheers

Stian

Answer (score 0):

This is a client-side based limitation, so the short answer is: no.

However there are websites and services that try to surmount this problem by using scripts (loading them on the fly).

[Have a look here](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/) and [here](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) (these articles are about generic cross-domain AJAX requests)

Comment: Well as far as I understand the client can issue cross-site ajax requests if the target server allows it by adding Access-Control-Allow headers to the response, as described [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

So the question is really if it is possible to enable the Autocomplete API WebService for a specific domain. That would involve (on Googles side) to match the API key in the request against a list of allowed referers.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow` only works on "modern" browsers (IE6 and 7 won't allow that)

Comment: That's ok because we don't support IE6 and 7 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The Places-API is also available inside the [Maps-Javascript-API](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html), you don't need to struggle with cross-origins there.

Comment: The AutoComplete functionality in Places Library is designed to add AutoComplete search to an existing input field. It does not allow for augmentation of the search result. That's why I want to use the Places Autocomplete Web Service.

Comment: I'm not talking about autocomplete, take a look at place-search-request : http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#place_search_requests

Comment: I'm aware of that Library, but it has certain limitations that makes it unsuitable for me, such as a radius limitation of 50 km, it's lack of matched substring information (which the Web Service does provide). The AutoComplete WebService also seems to provide much better results without requiring the user to type the full name of the Place that he's after, which what autocomplete search is all about.

Comment: If you don't like the JS-API create a proxy-script on your server for transmission.

Comment: Looks like that is what I need to do. The down side of that solution is that it will create an additional load on my server which I would have avoided if I could talk directly to Googles Web Service using Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Let me say its impossible to get around .I tried using java instead the code just works for http request(i used here is for graph.facebook.com):

```
public class search {
    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }

      public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
          String jsonText = readAll(rd);
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
          return json;
        } finally {
          is.close();
        }
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "172.16.0.2");
        System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
        JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=AIzaSyBRlMLIdoTk-j4OZCucR47rVMLhMmvZVRw&type=hospital&location=12.8213125%2C80.0442&radius=500&_=1427359809583");
        System.out.println(json.toString());
       // System.out.println(json.get("about"));
       // System.out.println("hello ");
    }

}
```

If you replace the link with places api web search it will not work,the reason is that google does not give its services on HTTP domain,,, and my code only works on HTTP domain(not HTTPS)